# Break in fabric8 kubernetes client mock server

Tags: fabric8

We were using fabric8 kubernetes client 5.3.x for watcher and it worked fine. Recently when we moved to 5.11.2 there were many changes observed and eventually the JUnit Tests started failing.

We use io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.server.mock.KubernetesServer

Earlier we were using ContainerStatus .withNewReady which now seem to be removed.
And then we added the following annotation
@Rule
public KubernetesServer myMockServer = new KubernetesServer(false, true);

After this, we are getting the following logs stating unsupported label requirement while the application code is sending this label.

[2022-02-03T07:30:22.733Z] 07:30:17.812 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.AbstractWatchManager - Watching http://localhost:40033/api/v1/namespaces/test/pods?labelSelector=app.kubernetes.io%2Fname%20in%20%28apps%29&timeoutSeconds=0&allowWatchBookmarks=true&watch=true...

[2022-02-03T07:30:22.733Z] 07:30:17.814 [MockWebServer /127.0.0.1:49882] **WARN io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.server.mock.KubernetesAttributesExtractor - Ignoring unsupported label requirement: app.kubernetes.io/name in (apps)**

[2022-02-03T07:30:22.733Z] 07:30:17.815 [MockWebServer /127.0.0.1:49882] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.server.mock.KubernetesAttributesExtractor - fromPath /api/v1/namespaces/test/pods?labelSelector=app.kubernetes.io%2Fname%20in%20%28apps%29&timeoutSeconds=0&allowWatchBookmarks=true&watch=true : {attributes: {namespace={key:namespace, value:test}, version={key:version, value:v1}, plural={key:plural, value:pods}}}

[2022-02-03T07:30:22.733Z] 07:30:17.815 [OkHttp http://localhost:40033/...] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatcherWebSocketListener - WebSocket successfully opened

[2022-02-03T07:30:22.733Z] 07:30:20.818 [OkHttp http://localhost:40033/...] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.AbstractWatchManager - Scheduling reconnect task

Is there something more should be done? Tests are in ERROR state and not Failed.

Sample JUnit program

```
  public void testAddNewPodWatchEvent()
  {
      //given
      doReturn(myClientMock).when(myTestObj).getClient();
      doReturn(myWatcherSpy).when(myTestObj).createEventHandler();
      String PATH =
              "/api/v1/namespaces/test/pods?labelSelector=app.kubernetes.io%2Fname%20in%20%28apps%29&timeoutSeconds=0&watch=true";
      Map<String, String> mockLabelMap = new HashMap<>();
      mockLabelMap.put("foo", "testlabel");
      mockLabelMap.put("app.kubernetes.io/name", "apps");
      Pod accPod = createAppsPod(mockLabelMap, true);

      myMockServer.expect()
              .get()
              .withPath(PATH)
              .andUpgradeToWebSocket()
              .open()
              .waitFor(100)
              .andEmit(new WatchEvent(accPod, "ADDED"))
              .done()
              .once();

      //when
      myTestObj.activate(mockProps);
      sleepForWatchToBeInvoked();

      //then
      verify(myWatcherSpy, atLeastOnce()).eventReceived(Action.ADDED, accPod);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a simple reproducer test code?

Comment: Added JUnit test in the problem description.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this?

Comment: I tried converting WatchTest.java in fabric8 to JUNIT-4 and ran and still it failed. Not sure what is the real problem here. 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/master/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/WatchTest.java